# how to store and update a variable in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I am pretty new to Java Script and HTML (so please go easy on me) - I have wrote a Java Script for a countdown. I already set it so it restarts when I click the button after the countdown finished. My problem now is that it kepps starting from the beginning when I refresh the page. I somehow need to store the time and date I clicked on the button so I can add 6 hours to that time again and the countdown won't renew everytime I refresh the page.
I read about global and session variables but I am not sure how to use them or if I can update them anytime (because the time I click the button keeps changing).

This is my current code:

```
var countDownDate = new Date(Date.now() + 5000).getTime();
var x = setInterval (calculate, 1000);

function start() {
countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate + 500000).getTime();
    $("#myBtn").removeClass().addClass("btnDisable");
    myBtn.innerHTML = "Bitte warten!";
window.onload = setInterval(calculate, 1000);
}

function calculate() {
// Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = hours + "h " 
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    $("#myBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#myBtn").removeClass().addClass("btnEnable");
document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = "Auf zur Raubtierfütterung!";

    myBtn.innerHTML = "FeedTheCat!";
return;
  }
}
```

And my current HTML:

```
  <div id="myTimer"></div>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btnDisable" disabled="" onclick="start();">Bitte warten...</button>
</div>
```

So right now I "store" the time I last started the countdown the first time and always add an amount of time (in order to do that I will set a specific time instead of "Date.now()+5000" - because that will keep reseting the time to the current one whenever I refresh the page). But I need to store the time I click the button and not the time I started the last countdown.

Could anybody help me? The countdown should run this specific time doesn't matter if who is logged in or refreshes the page. Also The button that it linked to the countdown shoul stay "open" as long as I haven't clicked on it.
The java script isn't excatly the best one but as I said - Im learning :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Session variables will not help you here, if you want the change to effect everybody, and not just yourself - there are some different methods of how to achieve this though.. f.eks you can make your click event write a timestamp in a file, and then read that files timestamp instead of using `Date().getTime()`. Or you could save the timestamp to the database somewhere, and read that timestamp with AJAX to a PHP script.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
How do I set a timestamp best? I just found methods to get back the timestamp but not how to create/update them...